# Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt

I have 2 projects running on different ports - 80 and 8005 on the same server. These ports point to example1.com and example2.com respectively. I installed SSL certificate for example1.com using https://tecadmin.net/install-lets-encrypt-create-ssl-ubuntu/ and it worked. However when I tried for example2.com, I got this error - `Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.`

I am guessing it needs example2.com to be port 80, is there a workaround this? How can I install a SSL certificate for example2.com?

Comment: Can you shutdown example1.com while you set up example2.com? What is the exact Certbot command that you are running?

Answer (score 2):

You must stop your server before you run certbot.

> That’s your problem–if your application is listening on port 80, then certbot can’t listen on that port, and therefore it can’t run.
> https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/problem-binding-to-port-80-with-standalone/50850/4

Then rerun the certbot command and of course start your web server again to continue broadcasting your sites.

Comment: `sudo service program_listening_on_80 stop` probably would do the trick. Just don't forget to start it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple workarounds but they aren't very good.

The problem is Let's Encrypt needs to verify you own the domain, and most typically they will only do that on ports 80 or 443.

The documentation of the verification types is [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/)

By default the system will attempt the HTTP-01 challenge, which is only permitted on port 80 (or port 443 from a redirect).

If you have a domain and a compliant DNS service you can attempt a DNS-01 challenge, but it's difficult to automate because of DNS propagation times.

If you have a working SNI reverse proxy (which is a much more difficult challenge) you could attempt a TLS-ALPN-01 challenge.

**Your best option is to temporarily shut down example1.com, run certbot for example2.com (with port 80) and then reactivate the original configuration.**